# ExtJS - Select visible element using Ext.dom.Query

Tags: javascript, extjs

I want to select elements with a specific class, but only when they are visible.
I'm trying to do this using [Ext.dom.Query](http://docs.sencha.com/extjs/5.0.0/apidocs/#!/api/Ext.dom.Query-method-select).
According to [this documentation](http://docs.sencha.com/core/manual/content/domquery.html), it should be possible using CSS value selectors.

I tried it with the following seletor

```
Ext.query('.x-box-scroller{display=none}')
```

but it results in an

> SyntaxError: An invalid or illegal string was specified

Many thanks for your help!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To avoid syntax error, try using different brackets:

```
Ext.query('.x-box-scroller[display=none]')
```

To select only invisible elements, I would go with:

```
Ext.query('.x-box-scroller[style*="display: none"]')
```

To select only visible elements:

```
Ext.query('.x-box-scroller:not([style*="display: none"])')
```

Comment: Thanks, but that does not work - Ext.query returns an empty array whether the  element has the style "display=none" or not...